# Angular: Close sidenav if a user clicks anywhere on the screen

Tags: angular

I am using a library for my sidenav and having an issue. I have to close the sidenav if the user clicks anywhere on the screen. I have tried few things but nothing is working for me.

Here's the code:

> html

```
 <ul class="navdrawer-nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" (click) = "hideNavbar()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" *ngIf="[1, 2, 3,5].indexOf(userRoleValue) > -1"
       [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">
       <svg class="mr-3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/><path d="M21 20a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H4a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V9.49a1 1 0 0 1 .386-.79l8-6.222a1 1 0 0 1 1.228 0l8 6.222a1 1 0 0 1 .386.79V20zm-2-1V9.978l-7-5.444-7 5.444V19h14z" fill="rgba(0,150,136,1)"/></svg>
        Dashboard</a>
  </li>
  ......
  ......
<main class="container-fluid" id="dView" (click) = "hideNavbar()"> //here I am trying to close the sidenav if the user clicks anywhere on the screen
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

> ts

```
hideNavbar()
{
  $('#navdrawerDefault').removeClass('show');
}
```

However, it's not working. The sidenav does not close when I click anywhere on the screen. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [ng-click-outside](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-click-outside) works really well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular directive for handling click events outside an element. Useful for things like reacting to clicking outside of a dropdown menu or modal dialog.

> Step 1

```
     `npm install --save ng-click-outside`
```

> Setp 2

```
import { ClickOutsideModule } from 'ng-click-outside';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, ClickOutsideModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
class AppModule {}
```

> Setp 3

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <div (clickOutside)="onClickedOutside($event)">Click outside this</div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  onClickedOutside(e: Event) {
    console.log('Clicked outside:', e);
  }
}
```

Learn More > [npm ng-click-outside](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-click-outside)